# Why EF Core generates INNER Join when selecting single entity without any Include()

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

Why following single entity query

```
this.DbContext.MaterialInfo.FirstOrDefault(m => m.KódMateriálu == "001");
```

generates INNER JOIN?

```sql
SELECT TOP(1) [m].[MaterialCode], [m].[Id]
FROM [Material] AS [m]
INNER JOIN [Material] AS [m0] ON [m].[MaterialCode] = [m0].[MaterialCode]
WHERE [m].[Id] IS NOT NULL AND ([m].[MaterialCode] = N'001')
```

---

Here is the EntityConfiguration:

```
public class MaterialInfoConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<MaterialInfo>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<MaterialInfo> entity)
    {
        entity.ToTable("Material");
        entity.HasKey(e => e.MaterialCode);                
        entity.Property(e => e.Id).HasColumnName("ID"); //legacy column, no longer a PK, but still and IdenityColumn 
   
        entity.HasOne<Material>() //maps to the same table
            .WithOne()
            .IsRequired(false)
            .HasForeignKey<MaterialInfo>(e => e.MaterialCode)
            .HasPrincipalKey<Material>(e => e.MaterialCode)
            .HasConstraintName("FK_MaterialInfo_Material_MaterialCode");
    }   
}
```

Comment: I guess because in your defition is `HasOne`, the inner join is there to make sure that indeed, your record has one matching record. Otherwise you could possibly return a record that has no matching records

Comment: "Otherwise you could possibly return a record that has no matching records" > But why would EF care?

Comment: I'm pretty much guessung here, but I assume it's the combination of HasOne, WithOne etc. that's forcing it to ensure that there is always a matching record.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mustn`t use

```
.HasOne<Material>()
```

replace it with

```
.HasOne<MaterialInfo>()
```

So we don`t have

```
.HasPrincipalKey<Material>(e => e.MaterialCode)
```

you must use

```
.HasPrincipalKey<MaterialInfo>(e => e.MaterialCode)
```

Comment: There are two Entities (Material, MaterialInfo) mapped to the same table. I need to configure relationship between them, otherwise the model is invalid and EF Core will complain. If I do as you suggest, there would be no relationship between Material and MaterialInfo

Comment: So you must share material configuration here